# Finding linear factors when a multivariate polynomial has them.

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, soft-question, algorithms

Which methods exist to factor a general 2 variable polynomial $$p(x,y) = \sum_{\forall {\bf i} = (i_1,i_2) }^{(N,N)}c_{i_1i_2}x^{i_1}y^{i_2}, c_{ij} \in \mathbb R$$

Into as many linear factors as possible? A linear factor is $kx+ly+m$ for constants $k,l,m \in \mathbb R$.